# Is there a way to import Components into index.tsx from the same directory of index.tsx

Tags: next.js

Is it possible to `import` React components from inside the page's directory ?
I can successfully `import` from outside `/pages/[...]/`.
`/components/[...]/` works just fine for instance. And that is cool for re-usable components.

But if I want to split a single page's components into separate files as follows :

```
/components
- SomeReusableComponent.tsx
/pages/[...]/
- index.tsx
- SomePageComponent.tsx
```

And `import` it into my main component :

```js
// /pages/[...]/index.tsx
import SomeReusableComp from '../components/SomeReusableComponent'
import SomePageComp from './SomePageComponent'

export default function MyPage(){
// page code
}
```

My build fails : `Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export in 
pages/`

Is there a trick to do that ? Some setting or else to tell nextjs that this file is a dependency and not a page ?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately that is not possible. All files within the `pages` directory for a Next.js project must be entry points (that subsequently get turned into routes) and cannot be imported from any other files in your project. Next "collects" all of these files in `pages` and processes them in a special way, so there is no way to avoid that currently.

Typically for reusable parts that I want to use in multiple `pages`, I create a component that accepts `children` as a prop.

For example:

`components/layout.js`

```
export default function Layout({children}) {
  return (
    <div className="some-styling-for-pages">
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

`pages/index.js`

```
import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default function IndexPage() {
  return <Layout>my page content</Layout>
}
```

Comment: Unfortunate, but nothing that I cannot work around ... Also you may reconsider your statement that all files within /pages/ must be entry files. I can have regular ts or js modules living alongside the "page component" without any compiling issue. Though this may not be recommended, now knowing that other components cannot be in that same directory. I will keep /pages/ as lean as possible and move all dependencies in another directory.